# Auto layout and UIViewAnimation - Gap between two connected views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I created a "tooltip" view that has a UILabel and an UIView with a CAShapeLayer for a triangle shape.
I have setup the "tooltip" so that the label is on top, with the triangle attached to the bottom and centered on the UILabel.

When I show the "tooltip", I use the UIViewAnimation with Spring Damping and Spring Velocity to give it a "pop" animation. This works great with one exception, a small gap can be noticed between the triangle and the UILabel during the beginning of the animation (which is then fixed when the animation ends.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**Here is the view/constraint setup:**

```
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.alpha = 1.0
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.addSubview(containerView)
    self.containerView = containerView

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    self.titleLabel = titleLabel

    let triangleView = UIView()
    self.addSubview(triangleView)
    self.triangleView = triangleView

    let views: [String: UIView] = [
        "containerView"  : containerView,
        "titleLabel"  : titleLabel,
        "triangleView"  : triangleView,
    ]
    let metrics = [String:AnyObject]()
    for (_, view) in views {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-8-[titleLabel]-8-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[titleLabel]-8-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    widthConstraint.active = true
    self.widthConstraint = widthConstraint

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    heightConstraint.active = true
    self.heightConstraint = heightConstraint

    let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
    trianglePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    trianglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 8.0, y: 10.0))
    trianglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 16.0, y: 0))
    trianglePath.closePath()

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = triangleView.bounds
    mask.path = trianglePath.CGPath
    triangleView.layer.mask = mask

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[containerView][triangleView]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[containerView]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-(>=8)-[self]-(>=8)-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(>=8)-[self][anchorView]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[triangleView(>=16)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[triangleView(>=10)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.triangleView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.anchorView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1.0).active = true

    let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: triangleView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    centerXConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow // Required to allow tooltip to grow beyond anchorView bounds without changing the anchorView constraints.
    centerXConstraint.active = true
```

**Here is the animation script:**

```
    self.layoutIfNeeded() // Set starting position for tooltip before animation

    self.widthConstraint.active = false
    self.heightConstraint.active = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.alpha = 1.0
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
```

Video:
[image]

Comment: Can you pls post the screenshot or gif of what error you are facing?

Comment: Rather than removing the constraint have you tried setting the constraint to the required height and width? e.g. `self.widthConstraint.constant = // label width` and `self.heightConstraint.constant = // label height` and then animating `layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @SohilR.Memon GIF added. Quality is poor, but you can see the gap just between the triangle and tooltip body briefly during animation.

Comment: @sketchyTech The problem isn't the label's height and width constraints (there aren't any, its just bounded by the parent view so it can grow). The issue is during the animation using spring damping/velocity causes the tooltip to slightly expand/shrink. During this animation, the tooltip "body" gets pulled away from the triangle, even though the constraint for these is setup to be edge to edge.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to subclass UILabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach it would be to have a custom UILabel

```
class ToolTip: UILabel {
    var roundRect:CGRect!
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawTextInRect(roundRect)
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        roundRect = CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width, height: rect.height * 4 / 5)
        let roundRectBez = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundRect, cornerRadius: 10.0)
        let triangleBez = UIBezierPath()
        triangleBez.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: roundRect.minX + roundRect.width / 2.5, y:roundRect.maxY))
        triangleBez.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:rect.midX,y:rect.maxY))
        triangleBez.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: roundRect.maxX - roundRect.width / 2.5, y:roundRect.maxY))
        triangleBez.closePath()
        roundRectBez.appendPath(triangleBez)
        let bez = roundRectBez
        UIColor.lightGrayColor().setFill()
        bez.fill()
        super.drawRect(rect)
    }
}
```

and then perform layout and animation like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var label:ToolTip!
    var labelTransform:CGAffineTransform!
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 100
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 200

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Push Me", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor).active = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(buttonHeight).active = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(buttonWidth).active = true

        label = ToolTip()

        view.insertSubview(label, belowSubview: button)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(buttonHeight).active = true
        label.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(buttonWidth).active = true


        label.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button.topAnchor).active = true
        label.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
        label.text = "This button is orange!"
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        let trans1 =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)
        let trans2 =  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, buttonHeight)
        labelTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(trans1, trans2)
        label.transform = labelTransform

    }

    func buttonPushed() {

        if label.transform.ty > 0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

                self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                }, completion:    nil)

        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations:  { () -> Void in
                self.label.alpha = 0

                }, completion:    {_ in
                    self.label.transform = self.labelTransform
                    self.label.alpha = 1
            })        }



    }

}
```

which creates the follow effect:
[image: Popup tooltip]

Comment: Great answer! Having one last issue though, which is allowing the label to resize to the provided text, and not be restricted to the anchorView's size (UIButton in your example). Suggestions?

Comment: if you take away the width and height anchors of the button or label then they will resize to the size of the text. However, what you probably want is some padding around the text proportional to it. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sketchytech/e5920de6c31651b44724) with that happening by utilising **boundingRectWithSize:**

Comment: I tried adding these constraints so that there is a minimum, but they never grow (self being a ToolTip instance):

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint .constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-(>=8)-[self(>=50)]-(>=8)-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint .constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[anchorView][self(>=50)]-(>=8)-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

Comment: @JamesHickman difficult to know where it's going wrong from this. I've not really used VLF except to write [this post](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/auto-layout-programmatic-constraints.html). Maybe check the [RW site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial) for guidance. Which iOS are you targeting? I believe there are issues with transforms alongside AutoLayout in iOS 7. If you are targeting iOS 9, I'd recommend using the approach I set out. Whichever approach make sure constraints are added after the views are added to superviews.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I'll keep playing with it. I am using iOS 9.0 as lowest target. I think the issue is where I set the roundedRect frame. It seems to set that as some sort of static frame instead of respecting the constraints. I'll play around with it some more. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah I narrowed the issue down to the method drawTextInRect. It seems what happens is any text that falls outside of the 'roundRect' bounds, just doesn't show.