# Gap between two connected UIViews with cornerRadius while animating

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I want to create a tipsView with a pop animate like this:

[tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fMr3.gif)

But as the gif show, there is a very thin gap between the two connected view while animating;

Then I made a demo to find out the main cause and finally got the `cornerRadius` property. Here is demo code:

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 214, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];
    
    self.subView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 214, 34)];
    self.subView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.subView1.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
    self.subView1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.subView1];
    
    self.subView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 34, 14, 6)];
    self.subView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.subView2];
    
    self.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
        self.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
            self.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
        }];
    }];
}
```

The gif:

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwXsb.gif)

and once I delete the line which used to set the `cornerRadius` property（or just set to 0）, its behavior was in line with expectations. The gif after deleting:

[demo after deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bak7M.gif)

**I wander why the `cornerRadius` property cause this result, and how I can fix it.**

I find a similar question and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027410/auto-layout-and-uiviewanimation-gap-between-two-connected-views), but I don't want to combine two views into one with bezier curve.

Comment: “I don't want to combine two views into one with Bézier curve” So you don’t want to fix the issue?

Comment: @matt the solution give in that link use bezierPath on only one UIView, but I want there still be two UIViews.

Comment: @matt the arrow of the tips may change for some big event,  bezierPath is not as flexible as image. So unless there is absolutely no way, I still hope to use image for the arrow.

Comment: You can redraw the image to make the arrow change. You can animate the change.

Comment: @matt sorry, I'm new for iOS. What does "redraw" mean? Did you mean use `drawRect` in somehow?

Comment: By saying "but I don't want to combine two views into one with bezier curve" you have ruled out this discussion.

Comment: @ArcherJo Make the triangle a little expanding to the top (like 2pt/pixel) and place it to your subviews tree right before you add the rectangular view. That way it is shown behind the rectangle and the expanded area will cover the gap. It is a simple solution and does what you want.

Comment: another way is to use CALayers or CATextLayer for the same approach instead of UIView's. This has the plus that you can also hang a CALayer into another one, so they will render from the inner most layer to the out most.. inner CALayers can overlap outer CALayers.. and you don't need a container then, because the first one is the container. Well actually the first Layer needs to sit in some View. Where each View in iOS comes with a layer.